# on selecting the drop down change lat long of Google Map using JQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

on selecting the drop down change lat long of Google Map using J Query or JavaScript 
please find the below code and assist me thanks for your help in advance

```
<form>  
    <select class="target">     
        <option value="-25.363882,131.044922" selected="selected">Brazil</option>
        <option value="4,3">China</option>   
    </select>
</form>

  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.target').change(function() {   
    var coordinate = $('select option:selected').val();
    alert(coordinate);
  //  alert(google_map(coordinate));
});
});

function initialize() {
    alert(coordinate);
        var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var map_options = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(coordinate , coordinate1),
          zoom: 4,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setCenter` to change the center of the map, and you'll need to pass in a `LatLng` object.

```
$('.target').change(function() {   
  var coordinate = $('select option:selected').val().split(',');
  map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(coordinate[0], coordinate[1]));
});
```

Syntax-wise, you'll need to pass in a latitude as the first argument, and longitude as the second argument. I'm kind of assuming that `coordinate` is structured that way.